# iOS Animation of image frame not getting right coordinates on Device orientation in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, animation, swift5

I need to create animation (from top left 10 to middle of the screen) when a `UIViewController` appears.

I have used `CGRect` frames for this but when I rotate my screen after the view is loaded, the animation view fails as the view needs to be aligned in center after the animation completes.

I have tried using auto layout as well but it does not make `UIImageView` to animate every time.

Here is the code which I am using currently.

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    imgView.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 80, height: 80)
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0, animations: {
        self.imgView.frame = CGRect(x: (self.view.frame.width / 2) - 40, y: (self.view.frame.height / 2) - 40, width: 80, height: 80)
    }) { (success) in

    }
}
```

Comment: try to make update your animation when view controller is rotated.

Comment: @Sukhwinder Singh- it wont make a change as self.view.frame.width remains same after view is loaded already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the right size of your `self.view.frame.width` during orientation changes you should override the `viewWillTransition(..)` method:

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
        // here you have the right size.width
}
```